# Problems with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jstl

I've got a collapsed table with link that collapses its content. I want to change link (for example, from "+" to "-" and backward) using JS. I did it, but my table stops collapsing. This is the code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

   <h6>
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
        id="element${result.index}" data-parent="#accordion"
        href="#collapse${result.index}"
        onClick="javascript:changeText(${result.index})"><span
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>&nbsp; ${result.name}
   </h6>

   <div id="collapse${result.index}"
   class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">
```

and so on. The function:

```
function changeText(idElement) {        
        var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);      
        if (element.innerHTML === '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>')         
            {           
            //element.innerHTML = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>';
            }
        else {          
            //element.innerHTML = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>';
            }
     }
```

If I comment `innerHTML` part, table collapses, but icon doesn't change. If I remove comments, icon changes, but table doesn't collapse. How can I avoid this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `innerHTML` because it removes event bindings. In your case you can simply change class names:

```
function changeText(obj) {
    var element = obj.children[0];
    if (element.className.indexOf('glyphicon-plus') > -1) {
        element.className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus';
    }
    else {
        element.className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus';
    }
 }
```

and use it will `onclick` attribute:

```
onClick="changeText(this)"
```

Answer (score 2):

First remove inline JS .... `onClick="javascript:changeText(${result.index})"`

Then attach a click event listener to the element, and toggle the classes rather than replacing the whole icon span element - replacing the element removes any event listeners bound to the element:

```
$(function() {
    $('[id^=element]').on('click', function() {
        $('span', this).toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one..

```
function changeText(idElement) {        
        var element = document.getElementById('collapse' + idElement);      
        if (element.innerHTML == '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>')         
            {           
            //element.innerHTML = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>';
            }
        else {          
            //element.innerHTML = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>';
            }
     }
```